# scoped style equivalent in html4

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of HTML that I need to modify and I need to keep the changes minimal (out of CSS). All I need to do is to hide a table cell until something happens. So I went ahead and added the style tag as shown below:

```
<td style="display:none;">
```

However, this causes the style class to reset, e.g. the cell which used to be vertically center-aligned is now top-aligned, and so on. My understanding is that this is because the style attribute overrides the default CSS stuff. Is that correct? If yes, how can I prevent it? I just need to add the display attribute, not reset the rest of style attributes.

I spend some time searching online and noticed that HTML5 has introduced something called scoped style. Is there an HTML4 easy-to-do equivalent for it?

Answer (score 3):

It might be because doing `display:none` remove the node from the DOM display calculation. You no longer have a placeholder for that cell in your table.  You might try `visibility:hidden`, which will have the DOM element keep its place in the document rendering but just not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try `visibility:hidden;` instead of `display:none;`

Let me know if that does the trick.